# 3D Builder is Saying "One or more objects is invalidly defined"

Tags: 3d-design

Currently, 3D Builder is telling me "one or more objects are invalidly defined. Click here to repair." What is this and what does it mean? When I click it, it totally messes up my model (I can't tell what it even did due to the orthogonal camera). Model stats:

- Made with Sketchup
- Used STL Exporter to export it
- Last I knew what the repairing did to it was to remove my sinks and reduced them to holes in the floor
- I used ASCII encoding for my STL (I tried using Binary, but it didn't help)
- I tried subdividing it but it didn't help.

Screenshots:

This is a picture of the model before repairing:
[image: This is a picture of the model before repairing]

This is a picture of the model after repairing:
[image: This is a picture of the model after repairing]

(Just in case you wonder. I actually **have** to use STL for this project)

Comment: There's almost never a reason to use ASCII encoding for STLs. Just stick with binary.

Comment: @Tom van der Zanden, I use binary now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How thick are those walls? 3D printers cannot print zero-width surfaces (and slicers cannot slice them). 3D Builder has tried to make your model printable, but obviously not in the way that you might have hoped for. You need to go back to Sketchup (or some other CAD package) and give the walls a definite thickness (and one big enough for a 3D printer to handle).

Comment: I can't believe that you answered my question in 11 minutes!

Comment: I just happened to log on. :D

Comment: Now the "repairing" just subdivides it!

Answer (score 3):

SketchUp is notorious for creating non-manifold (non-3D-printable) models. You would be much better off to learn to use a different, better suited program for your purposes.

Disregarding that aspect for the moment, your model prior to repair appears to be a general rectangular prismatic shape with dividers. Unfortunately, those dividers also appear to have zero wall thickness. One must create objects with thickness (minimum should be no lower than your nozzle diameter) in order to have that portion addressed.

Other views of the object may confirm this.

Back to the first reference, even a program as simple as [TinkerCAD](https://www.tinkercad.com/) will give you SketchUp simplicity with a much smaller chance of this sort of failure. For more advanced model creation with parameters, [Fusion 360](https://www.autodesk.com/products/fusion-360/overview) offers hobbyist free license. I'm also quite fond of [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) ( also free ) for parameter-based model creation.

Comment: I second Fusion 360 (and OpenSCAD).